# how to enable hardware Floating Point Unit (FPU) in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, fpu

I am have a linux system (x86) with RTAI installed on it, and I am using it for a control design application.

The exported c code of a continuous-time simulink model involves some calculations with floating point data, which off course not supported in kernel space, normally. But I have to force my hardware to perform floating point calculations since I don't seem to have any other alternative.

I have tried to google it a lot, but I didn't found anything to the point and straight forward.

any suggestions?

__

regards.

Comment: Sounds like an XY-problem. *Why* do you need the FP computations to be done in kernelmode?

Comment: XY problem. Why do you **think** you have to do the processing in kernel space??

Comment: @EOF: Hrmm, too slow ;-)

Comment: If it is not clear from what EOF and Olaf commented, userspace applications in Linux on x86 can use floating point hardware as they wish. The kernel doesn't use floating-point, because it does not need to, and not using floating-point registers means it can optimize their loading/unloading on each context switch. [**RTAI**](https://www.rtai.org/) is RealTime Application Interface -- for userspace applications (which, as I mentioned, can use FP HW freely).

Comment: well, the point of using FPU in kernel space is that I want to **__access the hardware directly__**, which I believe is not possible in userspace. I am aware that I can use fpu in userspace but I don't want to have any kind of bridge between hardware and my actual module because it would eventually slower the performance.
Moreover, my task involves the communication between two Linux-RTAI systems via EtherCAT and by doing so in userspace, the application has to read kernel module buffer every time when the buffer is full and process it.
so I have to have FPU enabled in kernel space somehow!